# Webpack config for cordova

Tags: cordova, webpack

I want to use webpack for my cordova application and using:

```
var dir_js = path.resolve(__dirname, 'www/js');
var dir_html = path.resolve(__dirname, 'www/html');
var dir_build = path.resolve(__dirname, 'www/build');
```

Is there a better way to define the 'www' one time instead as prefix for every dir definition?

Comment: Is this code in your webpack config file? Or is it on your source files?

Comment: @VinTem in my webpack config file.

Comment: This is for your output correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is in your webpack.config.js file, you can treat it as any other js file. What I like to do is to have a PATHS object with all my paths, like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var baseDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'www');

var PATHS = {
  js: path.resolve(baseDir, 'js'),
  html: path.resolve(baseDir, 'html'),
  build: path.resolve(baseDir, 'build')
}
```